# Webservice returns binary representation of an image, javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, image-manipulation

How can I take that binary string representation and turn it into an image using javascript. I am using jquery....

Do I need to do this using a server side script?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean "turn it into an javascript"?  What do you need to do with the image once you have it?

Comment: sorry typo... i meant it is giving me a string and i want to turn it into an image using js. I know how to do it using a server side script, but I am wondering about alternative options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about something like a base64-encoded image, you just need to use the [data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

[For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML), if the image is encoded in this string:

```
"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
```

then you create this `<img>` element:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="Red dot" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/s2mNa/